Split line after every [CHARACTER]
I'm looking for a vim motion to split a line into multiple lines, basically inserting \n after every [CHARACTER], whereas character is the one I type as part of a the motion.
E.g. this let's split this line into multiple:
ensure_installed = { "c", "lua", "vim", "vimdoc", "query", "elixir", "heex", "javascript", "html" },

Result should look like this:
ensure_installed = { "c",
"lua",
"vim",
"vimdoc",
"query",
"elixir",
"heex",
"javascript",
"html" },

is there some remap I could do, e.g. K, would split after comma (,)?

You might want to avoid mapping K, though: see :help K

Coming from another angle as Vivian's answer, you could create a user-defined command that accepts an argument such as:
:command -nargs=1 K s/<args>\(\s*$\)\@!/&\r/g

See :help :command for reference.
The negative lookahead \(\s*$\)\@! will prevent matches that are followed by any number of whitespace and an end-of-line, see :help /\@!.
This prevents adding yet another line break when a comma is already at the end of a line.
It's intended to make the command more convenient to use, feel free to drop it.
You can call it with :K,<CR>. That's two more keystrokes than the solution you wanted to have but the character (or string) to split on is variable and you keep the highly useful K command.
To allow for a range (with the current line as the default), you can use this variation on the command above as explained in :help :command-range:
command! -nargs=1 -range K <line1>,<line2>s/<args>\(\s*$\)\@!/&\r/g


That's a nice way. Could you give a way to specify this in lua and also allow ranges to work with it?

@glades range added. Unfortunately, I have no experience with Lua. I'm sure there's a short explanation somewhere how to translate from Vimscript to Lua.

It almost kinda works but is there a way to do it from selection start to selection end instead of the whole selected liens?

"It almost kinda works" - that's one way to say "it does far more than the original question asked for". You can constrain :substitute to match inside the visual selection with \%V but this works poorly with a command accepting a range. The solution would be to have one command to work line-wise and another one to work in visual selections.

For K, I would do:
nnoremap K, <cmd>s/,\zs/\r/g<CR>

I would repeat that mapping for the other mapping that make sense:
nnoremap K; <cmd>s/;\zs/\r/g<CR>
" ...

